# Query not showing the right results

Tags: php, mysql

I have build a query like this:

```
        SELECT 
           c.*,
           (SELECT COUNT(cursus_id) FROM cursusdienst_bestellingen where cursus_id = c.id AND datum_afhaling IS  NULL AND datum_verwijderd IS NULL AND studentid = '$studentid') as besteld,
           (SELECT COUNT(cursus_id) FROM cursusdienst_bestellingen where cursus_id = c.id AND datum_afhaling IS NOT NULL AND datum_verwijderd IS NULL AND datum_afgehaald IS NULL AND studentid = '$studentid') as afhalen,
           (SELECT datum_afhaling + INTERVAL 14 DAY FROM cursusdienst_bestellingen where cursus_id = c.id AND datum_afhaling IS NOT NULL AND datum_verwijderd IS NULL AND datum_afgehaald IS NULL AND studentid = '$studentid') as datum_afhaling,
           (SELECT COUNT(cursus_id) FROM cursusdienst_bestellingen where cursus_id = c.id AND datum_afgehaald IS NOT NULL AND datum_verwijderd IS NULL AND cb.studentid = '$studentid') as afgehaald
        FROM 
           cursusdienst c
        LEFT JOIN
           cursusdienst_bestellingen cb
        ON
           cb.cursus_id = c.id    
        WHERE 
           c.studierichting = '1ste Bachelor'
        ORDER BY 
           c.artikel asc, cb.studentid
```

This is a registration/ordering system for students and courses. There are a lot of student using this system. The student must be registered before they can order a course.
I have a problem with my query here because i see courses of every student in the same list. An example here:

```
Checkbox         Course              Price     Status
Checkbox         Course 1            12.00     Ordered
Checkbox         Course 1            12.00     Ordered
Checkbox         Course 2            25.50     Ready to deliver
Checkbox         Course 3            15.00
```

As you see here, the query shows me all the course info of 2 students (it is just an example) they are logged in and ordered courses.
The first student ordered Course 1 en 2 and the second student ordered only Course 1.
If i logged in as a student i want to see only my status with the course i have ordered but i see the rest of the courses as well (without any status like course 3) so i can order other courses in the same form.
What is not want to see is what others are ordered!

So i want to see only this if i, as a student, ordered Course 1 and 2. Course 3 is also in the list because i can order it now but i didn't ordered before (so it has no status):

```
Checkbox         Course              Price     Status
Checkbox         Course 1            12.00     Ordered
Checkbox         Course 2            25.50     Ready to deliver
Checkbox         Course 3            15.00
```

If i add "AND cb.studentid = '$studentid'" to the WHERE i see only my ordered courses and not the rest of the courses i didn't ordered.

**Edit: (thanks to SunKnight0) set the "AND cb.studentid = '$studentid'" in the ON part and not in the WHERE part! So the working code is shown below:**

```
        SELECT 
           c.*,
           (SELECT COUNT(cursus_id) FROM cursusdienst_bestellingen where cursus_id = c.id AND datum_afhaling IS  NULL AND datum_verwijderd IS NULL AND studentid = '$studentid') as besteld,
           (SELECT COUNT(cursus_id) FROM cursusdienst_bestellingen where cursus_id = c.id AND datum_afhaling IS NOT NULL AND datum_verwijderd IS NULL AND datum_afgehaald IS NULL AND studentid = '$studentid') as afhalen,
           (SELECT datum_afhaling + INTERVAL 14 DAY FROM cursusdienst_bestellingen where cursus_id = c.id AND datum_afhaling IS NOT NULL AND datum_verwijderd IS NULL AND datum_afgehaald IS NULL AND studentid = '$studentid') as datum_afhaling,
           (SELECT COUNT(cursus_id) FROM cursusdienst_bestellingen where cursus_id = c.id AND datum_afgehaald IS NOT NULL AND datum_verwijderd IS NULL AND cb.studentid = '$studentid') as afgehaald
        FROM 
           cursusdienst c
        LEFT JOIN
           cursusdienst_bestellingen cb
        ON
           cb.cursus_id = c.id AND cb.student_id = '$studentid'  
        WHERE 
           c.studierichting = '1ste Bachelor'
        ORDER BY 
           c.artikel asc, cb.studentid
```

Comment: Can you give examples results of what you are getting and what you expect to get?

Comment: I edited my question for you!

Comment: Your query results should have fields named bested, afhalen, datum_afhaling, afgehaald, 3 of which are counts so they should be integers and one is a date. None of these match your result examples.

Comment: I will take a guess anyway. Add `cb.studentid = '$studentid'` to the `ON` part of the `LEFT JOIN`, not the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I think this is correct now to set it in the ON part and not the WHERE part ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   c.*,
   (SELECT COUNT(cursus_id) FROM cursusdienst_bestellingen where cursus_id = c.id AND datum_afhaling IS  NULL AND datum_verwijderd IS NULL AND studentid = '$studentid') as besteld,
   (SELECT COUNT(cursus_id) FROM cursusdienst_bestellingen where cursus_id = c.id AND datum_afhaling IS NOT NULL AND datum_verwijderd IS NULL AND datum_afgehaald IS NULL AND studentid = '$studentid') as afhalen,
   (SELECT datum_afhaling + INTERVAL 14 DAY FROM cursusdienst_bestellingen where cursus_id = c.id AND datum_afhaling IS NOT NULL AND datum_verwijderd IS NULL AND datum_afgehaald IS NULL AND studentid = '$studentid') as datum_afhaling,
   (SELECT COUNT(cursus_id) FROM cursusdienst_bestellingen where cursus_id = c.id AND datum_afgehaald IS NOT NULL AND datum_verwijderd IS NULL AND cb.studentid = '$studentid') as afgehaald
FROM 
   cursusdienst c
LEFT JOIN
   cursusdienst_bestellingen cb
ON
   cb.cursus_id = c.id AND cb.studentid = '$studentid'
WHERE 
   c.studierichting = '1ste Bachelor'
ORDER BY 
   c.artikel asc, cb.studentid
```

Comment: Give the suggestion of astax the same results? Or is it better to do?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Is it about the other answer that was posted here? I don't think it was correct and it seems to have been deleted.

Comment: Yes, now i see. It's been deleted. No worries... Thanks for helping me out here ;-)